# Smoothings of isolated non-irreducible surface singularities

Tags: cv.complex-variables, deformation-theory, singularity-theory

Let $(X,0)$ be a normal surface singularity. Suppose that it does not admit a smoothing.

Is it possible that there exists an isolated surface singularity $(Y,0)$ reduced near $0$ which is not irreducible and $(X,0)$ is one of its irreducible components and such that $(Y,0)$ does admit a smoothing? Is there some obstruction for this to happen?

Are these kind of questions treated somewhere?

Comment: Are you assuming that $Y$ is reduced near $0$?

Comment: Yes, I assume that. I edited the equestion. Although, I would be happy with $Y$ being reduced along a component isomorphic to $(X,0)$.

Comment: If $Y$ is reduced near $0$, then you should be able to rule out deformations of singularities of $(Y,0)$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. Do you mean that $(Y,0)$ does not admit a smoothing because one of its components does not?

Comment: No, that is not what I am saying.

Comment: @JasonStarr I am sorry. Maybe it is the english that I don't understand. You said that I should be able to rule out (exclude) deformation of singularities of $(Y,0)$. Do you mean exclude some (a priori possible) deformations of $(Y,0)$? Or exclude deformations of some of the irreducible components of $(Y,0)$?

Comment: I mean exclude deformations of $(Y,0)$.  The scheme you have described is S1 but not S2.

Comment: There are non-normal isolated singularities (therefore not $S2$) that admit smoothings. The space $(Y,0)$ has a versal deformation. So again, I do not understand the sentence "exclude deformations of $(Y,0)$".

Comment: Certainly non-S2 singularities can admit smoothings, e.g., when two disjoint 2-planes in affine 4-space coalesce.  In that case, the central fiber is not S2.  Also, the central fiber is not S1.

Comment: In your case $X$ is a connected component of the normalisation $Z$ of $Y$. On p. 255 of http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/1978c--FootnotesRamanujam-NC.pdf Mumford attributes to Rim the result that $Z$ is local (so that $Z=X$) if $Y$ is smoothable. This seems to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that solves my issue. I guess this question was obvious for an expert. But still if you want write your comment as an answer, I will check it as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will adhere to Mumford's notation as much as possible.
Let $y$ denote the closed point of $Y$, $\mathcal O=\Gamma(Y,\mathcal O_Y)$, $\widetilde{\mathcal O}=\Gamma(Y-\{y\},\mathcal O_Y)$ and $Z=\operatorname{Spec}\widetilde{\mathcal O}$, which is the normalization of $Y$ in this situation. Then (Rim) $\widetilde{\mathcal O}$ is local if $Y$
is smoothable, so $Z$ is connected. Then $X=Z$, and then $X=Y$.